# Overriding in inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

```
// file name: Main.java 
class Base { 
    private void foo() {
        System.out.printf("Message");
    } 
} 

class Derived extends Base { 
    public void foo() {
        System.out.printf("Message1");
    } // works fine 
} 

public class Main { 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        Base d = new Derived(); 
        d.foo();
    } 
}
```

when I write `Derived d=new Derived()` it works fine but when i write `Base d =new Derived()` it gives error of private function cannot be overrided.

Comment: Private methods cannot be overridden.

Comment: Base doesnt have a public method named "foo". Derived does.

Comment: so why does it works when i make a derived class obj and refer it to by same.

Comment: @Saurav can you please check my answer, might help you to understand.

Comment: It works because `Derived` has public method `foo()` you can access from `Main`. `Base` doesn't have public `foo()`, only private, so it can't be accessed from `Main`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you say "It gives error of private fn cannot be overrided" - that's not the error you get when you try to compile this. It gives the following error instead:

```
$ javac Main.java
Main.java:16: error: foo() has private access in Base
        d.foo();
        ^
1 error
```

Why: Because `foo()` is a `private` method in class `Base`, so you cannot call it on a variable of type `Base`.

Also: You can indeed not override private methods; in fact, the `foo()` method in class `Derived` is a method that is completely separate from the `foo()` method in class `Base`, that just happens to have the same name. It does not override the method in class `Base`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because foo is private in Base class. You can use public or protected

Answer (score 0):

The method you want to inherit is `private`. So you don't `override` it. You hide it instead. So `Base.foo` and `Derived.foo` are completely different methods.

**Note: hiding private methods is valid**

I would suggest you to use `@Override` annotation on methods you override. It will prevent you from hiding private methods.